# Timezone changed Automatically when create new Date object in Java

Tags: java, android, datetime, timezone

I've  timestamp based on IST ( Indian Standard Time / GMT + 5:30 Hrs), My application shows last activity time based on device timestamp. 
that is current time - activity timestamp. Its fine when the device timezone is IST.

For example,

```
Activity timestamp - 11/Feb/2016 09:00:00 AM
Current timestamp (IST)  - 11/Feb/2016 10:00:00 AM
My Calculation = Current timestamp - Activity timestamp
So Application shows 1 hr ago
```

But the device timezone changed to some other like PHT for the same time (Philippine Time / GMT + 8 Hr)

```
Activity timestamp - 11/Feb/2016 09:00:00 AM
Current timestamp(PHT)  - 11/Feb/2016 12:30:00 AM (plus 2:30Hrs compare with IST)
My Calculation = Current timestamp - Activity timestamp
So Application shows 3 hrs 30 mis ago
```

My problem is, How to get the IST time always using java? whatever the timezone, I need IST time.

I tried below code, When i change the value to IST but the timezone automatically changed to device timezone.

Please refer below URL for source code http://goo.gl/dnvQF5

```
 SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
    Date date = new Date();
    // TODO: Avoid using the abbreviations when fetching time zones.
    // Use the full Olson zone ID instead.
    sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    String gmtDate = sd.format(date);
    System.out.println("GMT --> " + gmtDate);
    String istDate = gmtDate.replace("GMT", "IST");
    System.out.println("After Replace ->  " + istDate);
    sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
    try {
        Date istConvertedDate = sd.parse(gmtDate);
        System.out.println("After Convert --> " + istConvertedDate);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I got output like

```
GMT --> 2016.02.11 AD at 05:20:07 GMT                                                                                                                                              
After Replace ->  2016.02.11 AD at 05:20:07 IST                                                                                                                                    
After Convert --> Thu Feb 11 00:20:07 EST 2016
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: use a lib named JODA TIME

Answer (score 2):

The class `java.util.Date` is only a thin wrapper around elapsed milliseconds since UNIX epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). Objects of this type don't carry any format or timezone information. Therefore every such object has **completely lost the timezone information after parsing a text with timezone identifier or name** using `SimpleDateFormat`.

What you observe and are confused about is the fact that the method `toString()` of this class uses a specific representation based on the system timezone.

Another thing: If you apply a string manipulation replacing "GMT" by "IST" (an ambivalent timezone name - Israel? India? Ireland?) then you effectively change the moment/instant while keeping the local time representation. Do you really want this?

If you want to preserve the timezone information which was originally parsed then you could use `ZonedDateTime` in the library [Threeten-ABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) or `DateTime` in the library [Joda-Time-Android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) or `ZonalDateTime` in my library [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
    Date date = new Date();
    // TODO: Avoid using the abbreviations when fetching time zones.
    // Use the full Olson zone ID instead.
    sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    System.out.println(sd.format(date));
    String gmtDate = sd.format(date);
    System.out.println(gmtDate);

    //Here you create a new date object
    Date istDate= new Date();
    sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
    String istDate=sd.format(istDate);
    System.out.println(istDate)

   }
```

This way the first printed time will be GMT and second will be ISD.

Comment: I can able to get the IST date as string. But I need date object with IST. So only I can perform subtraction.

Comment: @Dhinakar `java.util.Date` does not carry any specific timezone - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.Calendar

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
```

this calendar contains current time in IST timeZone.

You can set timeStamp:

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp);
```

And get java.util.Date or time stamp

```
Date date = calendar.getTime();
Long timeStamp = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: I tried that too. But still same problem. Problem is when I  try convert the time to IST, the date object automatically changed to device timezone. :(

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
```

to

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
```